# No Releases Folder Generated in Deployment Capistrano Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using Capistrano 3.4 and Rails 4.2.

Initially, I could deploy my application with `cap production deploy`, everything was working great.

Suddenly, whenever I did `cap production deploy`, no errors at all are thrown, but my `current` folder was not being updated with the newest changes.

I then `rm -rf` my entire releases folder to start from scratch, run `cap production deploy`, and now there is no `releases` folder being generated, but still no errors are being thrown. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon my same problem, I was using a VPS and made an image of my dev server, and created my production server from it.

I made all the changes, but I forgot to update `config/deploy/production.rb' with the ip address of the new server, so nothing was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Every time before first deploy on server you should run

`cap production deploy:check`

It creates all needed folders, checks access rights and required dependencies.